# Which Stack Exchange is proper for asking optimization programs like ModeFrontier and Dakota?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to ask a question about **Optimization Programs** like *Esteco ModeFrontier and Dakota*. These programs are very used with simulation programs and very *engineers* uses them but inside the program contains very *mathematicians and biological concepts*.
Which Stack Exchange is most proper?

I have already asked a year ago on stackoverflow and because this I gain the badge Tumbleweed.

Finally, I answered my own question [How to solve java issue of mathcad integration node in modefrontier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167722/how-to-solve-java-issue-of-mathcad-integration-node-in-modefrontier)

Comment: Depends on what your question is exactly.

Comment: It's about error message, conexion problems with other softwares and how do some process, take resumes about results

Comment: If you have tried posting them on any sites already, which ones and the reactions of those sites would I think be worth including in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest @PolyGeo